# Android List View

Tags: android

In my Layout there are some widgets are there in above to the list view. When i scroll through the list view i want to scroll my layout fully.Please any one can suggest the answer

Answer (score 2):

Put the widgets that are presently above the `ListView` inside the `ListView`, either by using `addHeaderView()`, my [`MergeAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge), or your own custom `Adapter` class. The, those widgets will scroll along with everything else in the `ListView`.